# typeid operator in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, typeid

I have the following code

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name..." << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Data type = " << typeid(name).name() << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

According to the various textbooks and pieces of documentation I've read about the typeid operator, I should expect to read

```
"Data type = string"
```

as the output. Instead, I get the following

```
class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >
```

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? FWIW, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: C++ will often play tricks on beginners. Believe it or not, that little monster and std::string are the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.

Those text books, first of all, should have told you the result of `name()` is implementation-defined, and could very well be `""`. Secondly, that type *is* `std::string`. The `std::string` type is just a typedef of `std::basic_string` with `char` and friends.

Comment: In general compilers don't think in terms of typedefs, so - for better or worse - compilation errors display the actual types involved.  Same with typeid things... you need all the potentially different typedefs for the same type to resolve to the same typeid record, so obviously some version of the real name is the only good choice for `name()`.

Answer (score 4):

std::string is an alias for the `char` specialization of the `std::basic_string` class template.  That mouthful you see output is the full typename including all template parameters.