# Is there a C++ function to compare types of variables?

Tags: c++

In Python, to compare types of variables, there is the function "type", for example: a = 10 and b = "abc", type (a)! = Type (b). Is there anything like it in C++? I have a vector of objects of the base class and I want to see if an element of that vector has been declared as derived class.

Comment: There is probably a way to [check if an object is a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307765/how-do-i-check-if-an-objects-type-is-a-particular-subclass-in-c) of another object.

Comment: _I have a vector of objects of the base class_ If your vector is not store pointers you won't have any derived class objects in it?  [Edit] the question to include code showing your declarations and how you're using it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typeid operator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721078/typeid-operator-in-c)

Comment: This is a duplicate and I have seen a question just like this but was unable to find the exact one.

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide is it [How do I get the type of a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310898/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-a-variable) ?

Comment: Yes, that is the one thank you @LouisGo

Answer (score 5):

Yup its called typeID

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

```
if (typeid(a) == typeid(int()))
//code here
```

Comment: May want to note that `typeid` is an operator in the language, not a function.

Comment: This does not work with inheritance, derived classes (and objects) have different typeid's from their base classes.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, variables are statically typed.

```cpp
bool eq_typed = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(a)>, std::decay_t<decltype(b)>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `class D` that inherits from `class B`, and an `object` of type `D`.  But you only have a `B*` to that object for some reason.

Then `dynamic_cast<D*>(object)` evaluates to a `D*` that points to the same object.  There is a run-time check to make sure that the conversion is safe; if you try to cast your object to a derived type it doesn't inherit from, you get back a null pointer instead.

You can also `dynamic_cast` references, if this fails a `std::bad_cast` exception is thrown.

If you want to do these types of runtime casts, what you really want is a `std::vector<B*>`, not a `std::vector<B>`.  If you actually declare a `std::vector<B>` then none of them can ever be a `D`.  But a `B*` can point to a plain-old `B` or any of `B`'s derived types.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you suggest `std::vector<B*>` as opposed to `std::vector<B&>`?

Comment: @Oebele https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references

Comment: Technically, `std::reference_warpper` was introduced for such things.